# Google Play inapp subcriptions : how to know if a user already had the 7 days free test period?

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing, subscription

I use subscriptions in my app, with a 7 days free test period.

If the user test the premium version thanks to the 7 days free test period and then cancel his subscription, and one month later wants to subscribe again, he will not have again the 7 days test period. So he will pay directly without any 7 days test period.

The problem is that my unlock activity where I explain the premium features is always the same one and mentions : "7 days free and then XXX/month").

As I don't want to mislead my users, I would like to display something like "You already had a test period. If you subscribe, you will directly pay XXX/month"

How can I know from the Google Play servers if a user already had a test period ? I could save this info in the user's app preferences but not what I want. I want to get the info from the Google servers.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: My answer was deleted, so I will add comment. I hope it will be helpful for you.
You can check list of user subscriptions with corresponding statuses here: Google Play Developer API: subscriptions (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions)

Comment: A shame :( Why did they delete your answer? Would be great if you would give some java code ! Thanks.